# How to make a frequency table in R with two category columns?

Tags: r, dplyr, tabular, contingency

I'm trying to make the table below look more like the one below it, where each unique value of the first column `MIPS_Group` only appears once, does anyone know how this can be done?

```
df %>%
  count(MIPS_Group, WES_Cohort) %>% 
  arrange(desc(n)) %>%
  mutate(PercentageOfMatching = n / sum(n))
```

Current output:

[image]

Format I'm trying to achieve:

[image]

Comment: `kableExtra::collapse_rows` can do this.

Comment: Will you paste the output of `dput(df)` into your question?

Answer (score 0):

duplicated() is one of the possible solutions:

```
df %>%
  count( MIPS_Group, WES_Cohort ) %>% 
  arrange( desc( n ) ) %>%
  mutate( PercentageOfMatching = n / sum( n ) ) %>%
  group_by( MIPS_group ) %>%
  mutate( MIPS_group = ifelse( duplicated( MIPS_group ), NA, MIPS_group )
```

Comment: Please add used packages into your answers, users with no knowledge of `R` will have no idea where functions like `group_by` and symbols like `%>%` come from (ie, your answer is not reproducible)